# Bind PropertyPath to DataTable Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to bind PropertyPath Object to DataTable Grid.

I have this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var list = new List<string> { "(", ")" };
        var _datatable = new DataTable();

        foreach (var value in list)
        {
            _datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(value));
        }
        _datatable.Rows.Add();

        this.DataContext = _datatable;
    }
}
```

and an AutoGenerateColumns DataGrid in XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

I got this error

> Syntax error in PropertyPath 'Unmatched parenthesis '('.'.

Comment: What is `list` an `Array or a Generic Collection`

Comment: It does't matter what the list is ! I got the source from another place !

Comment: Well perhaps you would show more relevant code what does `Nom` in this line mean..? `list[i].Nom.ToString();`

Comment: I have edited the post , I copied this from the whole project , I simplified it to make it readable , I missed deleting that part . My question is clearer now , the problem is with binding the "Property Path Characters like pare thesis" to DataTable

Comment: Ah, finally you're making sense! Is it so hard to imagine what info is needed for other people to understand a question? Now I can repro your issue in WPF and I must admit it's weird. Other symbols as column names are OK, parentheses aren't. Unfortunately I'm a XAML dyslectic, so I hope someone else can shed some light on this.